# WCF - Is the services element mandatory

Tags: wcf

I think my question is rather simple, so I'll stick to the point:

Is it by any means possible to expose a service *without* specifying the `services` element and only the `serviceHostingEnvironment` element? I.e. would the below configuration be enough to host a WCF service? I'm asking because i've seen applications that - as far as I can tell - lack the `services` element, and I thought that was mandatory.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Service.svc" service="Namespace.To.My.Service" />
    </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Comment: That depends on what version of framework you are using.

Comment: @PankajKapare .NET 4.5.1 and IIS 8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WCF 4.0 you don't need explicit service configuration as opposed to prior versions. It automatically adds default endpoints if no endpoints are defined explicitly.
Whatever configuration you mentioned in question is called File-less activation and you can activate service without even having physical .svc file. In WCF 4 you can define virtual service activation endpoints like one you have defined.

WCF detects what contracts are implemented by service and then method AddDefaultEndpoints adds one default endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented by the service. Note that this behavior is only when no explicit endpoints are added (either programmatically or through configuration). Should you add one explicit endpoint WCF stops adding default endpoints and it gives control to developer to customize it further.

Comment: Alright I see. You say that endpoints gets added automatically, which sounds reasonable. But what about the `contract` of an endpoint. How can it possibly "guess" the contract to be used? Or must I define endpoints explicitly in the case my class implements multiple service contracts?